# What is a term for an item that is in use at the office and at 'home', but never lives permanently at either?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to develop an idea for an office asset/item tracker, and one of the requirements is to track the item's location. To stop users continually updating the details when they are working in the office or at home, I would like a category of 'Location' that represents something like a work laptop that is likely wherever you are working from but does not have a permanent location like the office or home.

Note: I believe that it is valuable to have this category as it is likely that the people who may look at the reports could deem that two binary locations of in/out of the office are too broad. I am trying to preempt this but want to avoid having 1000 meaningless categories like my house, my bag, etc.
Note: The asset tracker only really cares if the items are in the office or not in the office, but I wish to give users more flexibility and therefore provide a few as possible options but make each one as valuable as possible.

Clarification: Stuart F and Xanne make an excellent observation, "Never used in transit" was misleading, and I have removed it from the title. I meant that it is not essential to track items in transit as a transit category explicitly/implicitly requires the user to update the status once said transit has finished. So far, I believe Stuart F is the closest with Mobile, thanks Stuart F!

Comment: Welcome! Please take a moment to read about [the topics that are covered here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). In particular, questions that ask "what is a good name for this" are not covered. I suggest using the "edit" link to make this question less about your app and simply about the idea your looking for. Also, as one of the requirements for word requests, please give a sample sentence showing how such a word might be used. Even though your app won't use it in a sentence, this will help give better answers.

Comment: Some suggestions for "changes its location often" are *nomadic*, *peripatetic*, *peregrinal*, *perambulatory.* But I suspect you're looking for something more like "Location: *not fixed*." Or *changeable* or *indeterminate* or *optional*.

Comment: Hi Andy, sorry for not following the tradition, my bad! I had assumed my question came under Word choice and usage; maybe I got the wrong end of the stick. As the context is in an app, I thought it better to describe the use-case rather than the in a sentence. I will come back and edit the question with your suggestion. Lastly, your suggestions of nomadic, peripatetic, peregrinal, perambulatory are precisely the kind I am looking for, thanks 

Comment: Never used in transit? This may be a null set. Or a riddle.  Hey, I’ve got it! A set of keys. Oh, wrong car keys.

Comment: Use an ENUM field named *location*, and only allow two values: *office* and *home*.

Comment: *Mobile* would appear the simplest, although some items that are always with someone might be *personal*. No need for *peripatetic* or *peregrinationary*. (I agree that "Never used in transit?" is a bit of a problem, as it would exclude things like mobile phones and laptops, but I did know someone who transported an office chair between home and work.)

Comment: Xanne and Stuart F, both of you identified an error in the title, i have tried to clarify that in the post, thanks. Also, Stuart F I believe that you may have found the answer I am looking for, mobile is an excellent idea :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes" is not on-topic here.

Answer (score -1):

If "in/out" would have been okay had it not been so broad, perhaps simply "home/office"?